# Poco failing to send mail

Tags: c++, ssl, tls1.2, poco-libraries

I have installed the Poco C++ library (Release 1.12.4) with vcpkg on my computer and I'm trying to send a simple Mail by using the sample delivered on the [Github Page](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/tree/devel/NetSSL_Win/samples/Mail/src).`The script is compile with Visual Studio 17.

**The full code:**

```
#include "Poco/Net/MailMessage.h"
#include "Poco/Net/MailRecipient.h"
#include "Poco/Net/SecureSMTPClientSession.h"
#include "Poco/Net/StringPartSource.h"
#include "Poco/Net/SSLManager.h"
#include "Poco/Net/ConsoleCertificateHandler.h"
#include "Poco/Net/PrivateKeyPassphraseHandler.h"
#include "Poco/SharedPtr.h"
#include "Poco/Path.h"
#include "Poco/Exception.h"
#include <iostream>


using Poco::Net::MailMessage;
using Poco::Net::MailRecipient;
using Poco::Net::SMTPClientSession;
using Poco::Net::SecureSMTPClientSession;
using Poco::Net::StringPartSource;
using Poco::Net::SSLManager;
using Poco::Net::Context;
using Poco::Net::InvalidCertificateHandler;
using Poco::Net::ConsoleCertificateHandler;
using Poco::SharedPtr;
using Poco::Path;
using Poco::Exception;
using Poco::UInt16;

using namespace std;


class SSLInitializer
{
public:
    SSLInitializer()
    {
        Poco::Net::initializeSSL();
    }

    ~SSLInitializer()
    {
        Poco::Net::uninitializeSSL();
    }
};


int main()
{
    SSLInitializer sslInitializer;

    std::string mailhost("smtp.office365.com");
    std::string recipient("recipient@gmail.com");
    std::string username("MyMail@gmail.com");
    std::string password("MyPassword");

    Poco:UInt16 port = 587;

    try
    {
        // Note: we must create the passphrase handler prior Context
        SharedPtr<InvalidCertificateHandler> pCert = new ConsoleCertificateHandler(false); // ask the user via console
        Context::Ptr pContext = new Context(Context::CLIENT_USE, "");
        SSLManager::instance().initializeClient(0, pCert, pContext);

        MailMessage message;
        message.addRecipient(MailRecipient(MailRecipient::PRIMARY_RECIPIENT, recipient));
        message.setSubject("Hello from the POCO C++ Libraries");
        std::string content;
        content += "Hello ";
        content += recipient;
        content += ",\r\n\r\n";
        content += "This is a greeting from the POCO C++ Libraries.\r\n\r\n";
        message.addContent(new StringPartSource(content));

        SecureSMTPClientSession session(mailhost, port);
        session.login();
        session.startTLS(pContext);
        if (!username.empty())
        {
            session.login(SMTPClientSession::AUTH_LOGIN, username, password);
        }
        session.sendMessage(message);
        session.close();
    }
    catch (Exception& exc)
    {
        std::cerr << exc.displayText() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I already tried the code on my first computer and it works. I wanted to try it on my laptop but it raises following error:
`Poco::Net::NoCertificateException`
and after a while:
`SSL Exception: Error during handshake: failed to read data`

I located the error and it comes from this line:
`session.startTLS(pContext)`;

Thank you for helping me!

P.S: I don't use OpenSSL but NetSSL_Win, an implementation of the POCO NetSSL library based on Windows Schannel.